# Deploy Java war using docker

Tags: java, docker

I m a beginner in docker.

I wish to deploy an java ant war application using docker

I have installed docker in server1

Created a Dockerfile :

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8116
ADD myapp.war myapp.war
ADD jetty-runner-9.4.8.v20171121.jar jetty-runner-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
RUN mkdir temp_dir
CMD ["nohup", "java" , "-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=10000000" , "-Xms64m" , "-Xmx128m" , "-Djava.io.tmpdir=temp_dir" , "-jar" ,"jetty-runner-9.4.8.v20171121.jar" ,"--log" ,"myapp-docker-request.log" ,"--out","myapp-docker-output.log" ,"--port" , "8116",  "--path" , "/myapp-docker" ,"myapp.war" , "&" ]
```

build the image as :

```
docker build -t  myapp .
```

run as :

```
docker run -p 8116:8116 myapp
```

while listing :

```
[root@metafore-staging ~]# docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
068751d27d8f        myapp               "nohup java -Dorg.ecl"   9 seconds ago       Exited (1) 7 seconds ago                        berserk_lovelace
```

It is not get started ; reports as :

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run -p 8116:8116 myapp

2017-12-15 11:21:50.653:INFO::main: Logging initialized @148ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2017-12-15 11:21:50.661:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
2017-12-15 11:21:50.729:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Redirecting stderr/stdout to myapp-docker-output.log
```

I wish to check the deployed app (myapp) in the browser , using `http://server1:8116`
(Docker application were deployed in Server1)

I have deployed the `myapp` in the server1 directly to check the working , it works fine .
Need to deploy and check it using docker

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/whats-the-difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-docker-file-and-when-should-i-use

Comment: updated the question;

Comment: I don't think you need the nohup since that would put it in the background.  Since nothing is running in the foerground the docker container would stop. same with the & at end.  The job needs to be running in the foreground to keep the container running.

Comment: Yes ,now it's running.I need to run the container in background of the server. i have appended "-D", "BACKGROUND" in the docker file,now container was  running in the background ,i can check the java application in the URL . but in the server after executing the docker run cmd it reports as : `/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jovial_mccarthy (37d07c7c3d0bc327695091e9df4132b39967d23c5d302e97120710364a124cc5): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8116 failed: port is already allocated.`with out -D BACKGROUND` it is not showing any error

Comment: `[root@localhost ~]# docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
cd78ce9c0135        myapp               "java -Dorg.eclipse.j"   7 minutes ago       Created                                 jovial_mccarthy`  status not showing as running. with out "-D", "BACKGROUND" status shows running and port shown as 8116-->8116 tcp