# Multi stage build can't COPY file from previous stage

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a React application that I dockerized as a multi-stage build. First it builds the application to the `/app/build` directory and then nginx tries to copy that to serve it.

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json /app
RUN npm install
ADD . /app
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

However when I try to build the image, the second stage can't seem to copy `/app/build` from the previous stage.

```
$ docker build -t foo .
...
Step 8/8 : COPY --fromm=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf1f4930e894ad5b1d404943fb81e45cdd06b8a39abe434a342f5f90f4a1f58f/merged/app/build: no such file or directory
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the final step in the first stage where

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

should be

```
RUN npm run build
```

See [difference between CMD and RUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/whats-the-difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-docker-file-and-when-should-i-use).