# Why does Windows docker container exit early before sleep command finishes?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm using Windows server 2016 to spin up `windowsservercore` docker containers and am noticing what I think is incorrect behavior where the container exits very quickly even though it should be sleeping for over 15 minutes. I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
RUN powershell Start-Sleep -s 1000
```

I build the container with `docker build -t mybuild .` when in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`. I then run the container with `docker run mybuild` and it exits very quickly.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214133/7655137) it seems that a sleep should keep the container alive. That answer was showing Linux so not sure if that matters but I feel like the sleep process is running in either case and that's what determines if the container should exit or not on default

If I use interactive mode and/or (I tried all 3 combinations) a tty (`docker run -it mybuild`) it stays up until I exit the container's shell

Looking at the docker docs `run` executes the container in the foreground (like -it) although I don't understand why that would matter since the process should still be running regardless of the container being detached or not. I also tried running it in detached mode with `docker run -d` and it exits very quickly in that case as well.

I also tried running another command after the sleep but that still didn't work. The docker file then looked like:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
RUN powershell Start-Sleep -s 1000
RUN echo "hello" > C:\hello.txt
```

I looked at the [dockerfile reference for `RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) and it says that `RUN` in shell form executes the command using `cmd /S /C` on Windows. So I tried running this from my normal shell on my host Windows machine exactly like the `Dockerfile` specifies (`cmd /S /C powershell Start-Sleep -s 1000`) and verified that it works as expected.

What am I not understanding here? I'm new to docker and trying to learn but I can't figure out what's going on searching the internet and reading docs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between RUN and CMD in a docker file and when should I use one or the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/whats-the-difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-docker-file-and-when-should-i-use)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that there is a confusion about the `RUN` command in dockerfile: its not saying what is going to run when the container will start, it just a command to run when building the image (like run this installation command..).
I think you are looking for one of the two options:

The `CMD` line in the dockerfile ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)):

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
CMD ["powershell", "Start-Sleep", "-s", "1000"]
```

or, you can run it from command-line:

```
docker run -d mybuild <your command>
```