# Run a repository in Docker

Tags: docker

I am super new to Docker. I have a repository (https://github.com/hect1995/UBIMET_Challenge.git) I have developed in Mac that want to test it in a Ubuntu environment using Docker.
I have created a Dockerfile as:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git

RUN git clone https://github.com/hect1995/UBIMET_Challenge.git

WORKDIR /UBIMET_Challenge

RUN mkdir build

WORKDIR build

RUN cmake ..

RUN make
```

Now, following some examples I am running:

`docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name trial`

But I do not see the output of the terminal from the docker to see what is going on. How could I create this docker and check what things I need to add and so on and so forth while inside the docker

Comment: First build image, next run it, see this https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

add '`-it`' and remove '`--detach`'

or add `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile` and use `docker exec -it` to access your container

**Longer explanation:**

With this command

```
docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name trial image_name
```

you tell docker to run image `image_name` as container named `trial`, expose port `8080` to host and `detach` (run in background).

Your Dockerfile does not mention which command should be executed (`CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`), however your image extends '`ubuntu:18.04`' image, so docker will run command defined in that image. It's `bash`.

Your container by default is in non interactive mode so bash has nothing to do and simply exits. Check this with `docker ps -a` command.

Also you have specified `--detach` command which tells docker to run container in background.

To avoid this situation you need to remove `--detach` and add `-it` (interactive, allocate pseudo-tty). Now you can execute commands in your container.

**Next step**

Better idea is to set `ENTRYPOINT` to your application or just hang container with '`sleep infinity`' command.

try (sleep forever or run /opt/my_app):

```
docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name trial image_name sleep infinity
```

or

```
docker run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name trial image_name /opt/my_app
```

You can also define ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT=sleep infinity
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT=/opt/my_app
```

then use

```
docker exec -it trial bash #to run bash on container
docker exec trial cat /opt/app_logs #to see logs
docker logs trial # to see console output of your app
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to provide and `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` layer to your docker file I believe.

Right now, it configures itself nicely when you build it - but I'm not seeing any component that points to an executable for the container to do something with.

You're probably not seeing any output because the container 'doesn't do anything' currently.

Checkout this breakdown of CMD: [Difference between RUN and CMD in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile)