# Read input of shell script in Docker container

Tags: docker, sh

I have a docker image of simple shell script. The shell script simply contains 1 method. and that method is expecting input from user. and then displaying the result which user has provided into the screen.

```
#!/bin/bash

executeScript() {
    echo "this is a shel script";
    read -p 'Enter value: ' value;
    echo $value;
}

executeScript
```

Now I have my docker file like

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD example.sh /opt/example.sh
RUN /opt/example.sh
```

Now I have created image using `docker build -t example-image .`
The image got created.
Now I need to execute the container.
while executing the container I want the shell script should wait for user input
How can I achieve?

If I execute `docker run -it --name example-container example-image:latest` I am not getting the actual output

The expected output should be like if I execute only shell script without docker

[image]

How can I run the container so that I can get the output like image attached

Comment: This might help: [Difference between `RUN` and `CMD` in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 3):

Follow the given steps.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /opt
COPY example.sh .
CMD ["sh", "example.sh"]
```

Build

```
$ docker build -t input .
```

Run

```
$ docker run -it input
this is a shel script
Enter value: 3
3
```

Comment: In my Dockerfile I already have string in CMD like
CMD ["abc"]

Is it allowed to pass any number of arguments in CMD?like
CMD ["abc","sh", "example.sh"]
??

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is using `RUN` in the Dockerfile - it executes the script at that point, during image creation (which does not accept input - so it returns immediately). Instead, you should use [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) or [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to change the executable when you start the container:

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD example.sh /opt/example.sh

CMD /opt/example.sh
```