# Dockerfile: copy zip and open it

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, unzip

I am trying to build a Windows docker image which will copy my software to the image and unzip it.
I am working on Windows 10 host.
The steps are:

1. Prepare file Dockerfile. with the following lines:

   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

   COPY image.zip c:\image.zip

   CMD ["powershell.exe", "Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\image.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:\'"
2. Prepare a zip file called image.zip with some files.
3. Run command:

   docker build -t test3 .
4. At this point the image is built. image.zip was copied to the image.
5. Run the container:

   ```
   docker run --rm -it test3 powershell
   ```
6. From the container powershell run:

   ```
   dir
   ```

At this point, I expect to see the content of "image.zip" which has been extracted during the build. But I don't, there is just "image.zip".

Comment: The command you provide on the `docker run` command line runs instead of the image's `CMD`.  Do you mean to `RUN` the command to extract the archive?

Comment: No, I want the file to be unzipped during the BUILD process, not the RUN. I guess this is what I am trying to find out: how to unzip a file as part of the build process using DOCKERFILE.

Comment: `RUN` does run as part of the build; `CMD` specifies the command that should be run when the container is started.  See also [Difference between RUN and CMD in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile).

Answer (score 7):

Found a way to do it using .tar file insead of .zip and using "ADD" instead of "COPY":

The DOCKERFILE. now looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ADD test3.tar c:/
```

The ADD command extracts the archive.

Answer (score 5):

that's true ADD instruction extract the archived files but not all formates .. for example `ADD` or `COPY` instruction does not support extracting `.zip` files but `.tar` files and some more.

I suggest to do the following:

1. copy the zip file from it's source manually to the working directory which contains the `Dockerfile`
2. use `ADD` instruction to copy the zip file from the source to the destination
3. user `RUN` instruction after `ADD` instruction to extract the zip file.
   like:

```
ADD <file_name.zip> /<destination> 
RUN unzip <file_name.zip>
```

4. after that continue writing your `Dockerfile` instructions.