# dbt_deps No packages were found in packages.yml

Tags: dbt

I am trying to configure dbt_utils for dbt with github. I have the following in my packages.yml file:

```
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils   
    version: 0.8.0
```

https://github.com/actonmarketing/actondata/blob/main/packages.yml

And I have removed packages from my gitignore file.

When I run dbt deps I get a message saying no packages found in packages.yml.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What was exactly your error message?

Comment: I am also getting the error

Error Message:
`05:23:10  Running with dbt=1.0.1
05:23:10  Warning: No packages were found in packages.yml`

Answer (score 1):

`packages.yml` needs to be at the same hierarchy level as `dbt_project.yml`

moving `packages.yml` from `project_name/dbt_packages/packages.yml` to `project_name/packages.yml` worked for me.

--

If you want it to live in a subdirectory, see the dbt docs here :

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management#project-subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to save your packages.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77195899/13908082:

You have to change the packages-install-path.

Example: packages-install-path: ../packages

NB: Note the '../' at start !