# Install python library from a git repo in docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

In my local machine, I am installing an unofficial python package (not released) from a git repo using the following command

```
python -m pip install "mod1 @ git+https://github.com/....git"
```

How can I install the library inside a docker file?

Comment: Just run the same command as part of the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

If the docker container is running, and you are not running interactively inside the container, you can use the `exec` command:

```
docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> python -m pip install "mod1 @ git+https://github.com/....git"
```

If you are inside a container, you should be able to use the command as is, assuming you have installed python in the container (i.e. command 'python' not found).

From a dockerfile, [depending on your needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile), you could use the `RUN` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run).