# How to launch Docker Compose and run curl together from dockerfile

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-kafka-connect

I have a problem with write a dockerfile for my application. My code is beloy:

```
# define a imagem base
FROM ubuntu:latest

# define a owner image
LABEL maintainer="MyCompany"

# Update a image with packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 8089

# Command to start my docker compose file
CMD ["docker-compose -f compose.yaml up -d"]

# Command to link KafkaConnect with MySql (images in docker compose file)
CMD ["curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
localhost:8083/connectors/ -d "
{ \"name\": \"inventory-connector\",
      \"config\": { 
            \"connector.class\": \"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector\",
            \"tasks.max\": \"1\", 
            \"database.hostname\": \"mysql\",
            \"database.port\": \"3306\",
            \"database.user\": \"debezium\",
            \"database.password\": \"dbz\",
            \"database.server.id\": \"184054\",
            \"database.server.name\": \"dbserver1\",
            \"database.include.list\": \"inventory\",
            \"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"kafka:9092\",
            \"database.history.kafka.topic\": \"dbhistory.inventory\"
      }
}"]
```

I know there can only be one CMD inside the dockerfile file.
How do I run my compose file and then make a cURL call?

Comment: It's a little bit unusual to run `docker-compose` as the main command in a container; usually you'd just run it on the host to start your other containers.  You could run the `curl` command as part of the startup sequence in one of the other containers, or in principle you could include it as a "service" that Compose launches.

Comment: #1 Did you solve your problem? #2 Do you need to set the connection values of one container in your docker-compose.yml ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RUN` command for this. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462208/4343332) for the difference between `RUN` and `CMD`.

If your second `CMD` is the final command inside the Dockerfile, then just change the following line:

```sh
# Command to start my docker compose file
RUN docker-compose -f compose.yaml up -d
```

If you have more commands to run after the `CMD`s you have now, try the below:

```sh
# Command to start my docker compose file
RUN docker-compose -f compose.yaml up -d

# Command to link KafkaConnect with MySql (images in docker compose file)
RUN curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
localhost:8083/connectors/ -d "
{ \"name\": \"inventory-connector\",
      \"config\": { 
            \"connector.class\": \"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector\",
            \"tasks.max\": \"1\", 
            \"database.hostname\": \"mysql\",
            \"database.port\": \"3306\",
            \"database.user\": \"debezium\",
            \"database.password\": \"dbz\",
            \"database.server.id\": \"184054\",
            \"database.server.name\": \"dbserver1\",
            \"database.include.list\": \"inventory\",
            \"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"kafka:9092\",
            \"database.history.kafka.topic\": \"dbhistory.inventory\"
      }
}"

# To set your ENTRYPOINT at the end of the file, uncomment the following line
# ENTRYPOINT ["some-other-command-you-need", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option - run the `curl` from within the Kafka Connect container that you're creating. It looks something like this:

```yaml
  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0
    container_name: kafka-connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        #
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:1.5.0
        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
        #
        echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost ⏳"
        while : ; do
          curl_status=$$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:8083/connectors)
          echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$curl_status " (waiting for 200)"
          if [ $$curl_status -eq 200 ] ; then
            break
          fi
          sleep 5 
        done
        echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Data Generator source"
        curl -s -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/inventory-connector/config \
            -d '{ 
                "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
                "tasks.max": "1", 
                "database.hostname": "mysql",
                "database.port": "3306",
                "database.user": "debezium",
                "database.password": "dbz",
                "database.server.id": "184054",
                "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
                "database.include.list": "inventory",
                "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
                "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory"
        }'
        sleep infinity
```

You can see the [full Docker Compose here](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml)