# ViteJS with docker cannot find module npm run install

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, vite

with my Docker file

```yaml
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD npm run dev

EXPOSE 4000

ENV NODE_ENV development
```

and docker compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: train_vite
    working_dir: /app/
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/app
    command:
      - npm run install
      - npm run dev
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
```

and vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server:{watch:{
    usePolling:true,
    },
    host:true,
    strictPort:true,
    port:4000
  }
})
```

throws an error like this
[image]
the command I run is
docker compose up

I try to run a docker image with the app folder linked to the docker folder (volume) to see the changes on live.

Answer (score 1):

A single [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) can be specified in a compose definition as a string:

```
"/run/this/command witharg"
```

or an array of the command and its arguments.

```
[ "/run/this/command", "witharg" ]
```

The existing definition is attempting to execute a binary called
`npm run install` with the argument `npm run dev`

Updating the example as a string:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: train_vite
    working_dir: /app/
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/app
    command: "npm run dev"
```

or as an array

```
    command: [ "/usr/local/bin/npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

To run multiple commands at startup, the build would need a script in the container and that script used as a [`command` or `entrypoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462208/1318694).

Comment: It helps to resolve my issue. 
Thanks