# docker exposed/published port not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, port

I have a *web* server (JS) I want to run into container, it runs but I cannot connect to it from host.
I am a docker noob so I took a basic script and Dockerfile that worked for a similar case with go server

here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker image build --file Dockerfile --tag guess-image .
docker container run --detach  --publish 3000:3000 --rm --name guess-container guess-image
```

here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

# download the file with server
RUN wget address/where/to/download/zipped-JS.server

# extract
RUN apk add unzip
RUN unzip server.zip
WORKDIR ./server/

#unrelated stuff
...
    
# install javascript and install the server
RUN apk add npm
RUN npm install

# exposing port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# run server
RUN node server.js
```

here is the docker `ps result` :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
5c8028cb79c3   3723e0b6e109   "/bin/sh -c 'node se…"   57 seconds ago   Up 57 seconds   3000/tcp   quirky_buck
```

when not dockerized, the JS server worked perfectly when browsing to http://localhost:3000/
I chose not to paste JS server but I can do it if you think it is relevant.

so any comment on those script is welcome
(for example : my guts tells my it is far from being as lean as possible and also naming is far from what I would expect ... )

---

edit as pointed by David changing the last line by

```
# run server
CMD ["node" ,"server.js"]
```

made it work

---

edit
this is not a **web** server just a simple local server that run in a browser and offer UI to test a script against another. Sorry for the awful wording.

Comment: I know i runs because it prints what it is supposed to print when successfully starting "~listening to port :3000"

Comment: I don't think your image build is ever finishing.  You're trying to `RUN` the server as part of the image build, but you need to set `CMD node server.js` as the main command when the container runs.  Also see [Difference between RUN and CMD in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile).

Comment: @DavidMaze well I tried this before but it did not work , but now , it works.
, thanks

Comment: your server code should listen on all network interfaces (0.0.0.0) not only on localhost interface