# How to make Docker container automatically activate a conda environment?

Tags: python, bash, docker, anaconda, conda

I'm working on dockerizing a conda environment so I've created a toy example.  My main goal is to end up with the following:

- A docker image
- A docker container that automatically loads the conda environment
- A docker container that can accept arguments for executables in the conda environment (e.g., `docker run [some arguments] "seqkit -h"`
- A docker container that will be interactive if no arguments are given but will automatically be in the conda environment.

For simplicity, I've created a docker container that installs [`seqkit`](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/) through `conda`.

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ARG ENV_NAME

SHELL ["/bin/bash","-l", "-c"]

WORKDIR /root/

# Install Miniconda
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda init bash && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels jolespin && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels bioconda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda update conda -y && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy

# =================================

# Add conda bin to path
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# Create environment
RUN conda create -n ${ENV_NAME} -c bioconda seqkit -y

# Activate environment
RUN conda activate ${ENV_NAME}

# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate ${ENV_NAME} && exec /bin/bash"]
```

Here is my command to build the docker image:

```
docker build --build-arg ENV_NAME=test_env -t test -f Dockerfile-test .
```

Issues:

**1. When I run the container, it does not activate the `test_env` environment automatically.  How can I make it so when I run my docker image to build a container it automatically activates `test_env` regardless of the commands given?**

```
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:docker jespinoz$ docker run -it test bash
(base) root@19dcf0f9570f:~# echo $CONDA_PREFIX
/opt/conda
(base) root@19dcf0f9570f:~# conda activate test_env
(test_env) root@19dcf0f9570f:~# echo $CONDA_PREFIX
/opt/conda/envs/test_env
```

**2. How am I able to give it commands once the environment is activated? My test command I want t**o run is just `seqkit -h`

Comment: Add `"-l"` to the `SHELL`

Comment: What does -l do?

Comment: Has the shell launch in login mode and thus load the initialization script, which is where puts the `conda init` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
# =================================
# Miniconda3
# =================================

FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ARG ENV_NAME

SHELL ["/bin/bash","-l", "-c"]

WORKDIR /root/

# Install Miniconda
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda init bash && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels jolespin && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels bioconda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda update conda -y && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge mamba -y && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy

# =================================

# Add conda bin to path
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# Create environment
RUN mamba create -n ${ENV_NAME} -c bioconda seqkit -y

# Set up environment
RUN echo "conda activate ${ENV_NAME}" >> ~/.bashrc

# Set entrypoint to bash
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-l", "-c"]
```

Here's how you activate it interactively:

```
docker run -it test  -c "bash"
```

Here's how you run commands:

```
docker run -it test  -c "seqkit -h"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add

```
CMD ['conda', 'activate', '${ENV_NAME}']
```

at the end of the Dockerfile.

You can look at the difference between *RUN* and *CMD* commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile#:%7E:text=RUN%20is%20an%20image%20build,you%20launch%20the%20built%20image.)

Comment: From my (limited) understanding of docker is that any commands given will override this.