# Building whatsapp web js proyect with docker. Building never ends

Tags: javascript, docker, build, whatsapp

I'm currently working on a WhatsApp bot project using the library Whatsap web js. It works great locally, my code works and connects to WhatsApp but I'm running into a problem when having to build it. I'm using docker for this matter.

When running `docker build` it runs everything (It took me a while but I managed to do it) and then it gets stuck right after my script is executed.

```
RUN node index.js
Client is ready.
```

It gets stuck there. The funny thing is that the bot connection is up while in the building process. The thing which I think (with my poor knlowedge in docker (Its my first time using it) it shouldnt happen.

I tried changing my docker configurations but nothing really changes. Also I tried seeing the log of the build but it has really no errors, it just... never finishes.

Comment: `RUN` runs as part of the image build; the image won't be built until the `RUN` command completes (your server exits).  You probably want this to be the `CMD` instead.  Also see [Difference between RUN and CMD in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461868/difference-between-run-and-cmd-in-a-dockerfile).

Comment: Great! thanks! Now it builds!!!!!! 

How do I upvote your response?